# Downcase character after a symbol in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string

I wish to downcase characters that appear after the symbols '(' and ')' in my string.

So far I have tried the following:

```
brackets_array = s.scan(/[\(|\)]/)
          brackets_array.each do |bracket|
            index_of_next_letter = my_string.index(bracket).next
            my_string[index_of_next_letter] = my_string[index_of_next_letter].downcase
          end
```

But this does not work if the string has more than one pair of brackets(eg. 'foo(bar) (new) foo'), as every time index(bracket) will return the index of the first bracket it encounters.
How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.gsub` will be much simpler:

```
str = 'foo(BAR) (NEW) foo'
str = str.gsub(/\((.+?)\)/) { |s| s.downcase }
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the ans. I'm not that good with regex, if you could pls tell me the meaning of "(.+?)", it would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rads non greedy match for any one more chars.